# Facebook/instagram link from webpage returns 404 on ios devices

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, firebase, facebook

I made a webapp and shared the link to the website via Facebook.
**On all Android devices it is perfectly working!**

But on **ios** you can only enter the main page (https://website)
If you want to get to the subpages like (https://website/**contact**) the website is returning **404** on all **ios** devices.

android:
[image: android view]

ios:
[image: ios view]

I tried to rescrape the website via [facebook api](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)
but it's not working still.
Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i included this to my firebase.json and its working now.

```
"rewrites": [ 
  { "source":"**", "destination": "/index.html" }
],
```